# How to make sure cloudfront behavior uses the correct origin without trailing slash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

We are hosting several projects with separate Hosted Origins on a single cloudfront. The cloudfront has a default behavior that points to `Origin1` .
We can access this by going to `website.com`
There is a second behavior for the subdirectory `/experience` that should point to another origin, `Origin2` .

The cloudfront uses a Cloudfront function to handle the trailing `/` as follows

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    // Check whether the URI is missing a file name.
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += 'index.html';
    }
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file extension.
    else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri += '/index.html';
    }

    return request;
}
```

When going to `website.com/experience/` the expected result of `Origin2` happens. However, if you leave off the trailing slash with `website.com/experience` the Origin seems to point to `Origin1` . The `index.html` of `/experience` is called, but the file paths in that folder expect the root to be `/experience`, however the origin still points to `Origin1`. Is there any way to set the behavior of `/experience` to point to the correct origin?

I looked into the Cloudfront functions to do a redirect, but it looks like you cannot change the origin.

> When a function changes the uri value, it doesn’t change the cache behavior for the request or the origin that an origin request is sent to.

From [Cloudfront Functrions event Structure | Request Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-event-structure.html)

We also set up a static hosted s3 Bucket to host a project in, and the same results happen with a subdirectory of `/experience` in that Bucket. The origin path on the cloudfront had a path pattern of `/experience*`  and the origin path was `/experience`

AWS Buckets are "linear" so there is no heirarchy, but I would expect if the directory name is there, or the cloudfront behavior points to the correct origin that there wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. Like you said, changing the `uri` doesn't change the origin.

You can do a URL redirect to handle the `website.com/experience` path:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;

    // Check whether the URI is missing a file name.
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += 'index.html';
    }
    // Check whether the URI is missing a file extension.
    else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri += '/index.html';
    }
    // Check /experience path
    else if (uri === '/experience') {
      var response = {
                statusCode: 302,
                statusDescription: 'Found',
                headers:
                    { "location": { "value": Origin2-PATH } }
                }

       return response; 
   }

    return request;
}
```